# Need help creating Job Settings for AWS MediaConvert in php

Tags: php, amazon-web-services

I have been trying to create a MediaConverter job using the latest AWS SDK for PHP (7.4.2) and I'm getting really stuck at creating the job settings correctly. I was wondering if anyone could look at this php code and tell me if I'm just completely on the wrong track. The response I'm getting is:

> Error executing "CreateJob" on "https://asdf.mediaconvert.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/2017-08-29/jobs"; AWS HTTP error: Client error: `POST https://asdf.mediaconvert.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/2017-08-29/jobs` resulted in a `400 Bad Request` response: { "errorType": "BadRequestException", "httpStatus" : 400, "requestId" : "388473f1-92af-4253-940c-00307b7c2a79", (truncated...) BadRequestException (client): The request could not be interpreted. - { "errorType": "BadRequestException", "httpStatus" : 400, "requestId" : "388473f1-92af-4253-940c-00307b7c2a79", "message" : "The request could not be interpreted.", "settingsValidationErrorsJsonBlob" : "" }

I actually copied the JSON for the settings directly out of MediaConvert, so I assume that my issue lies in trying to convert this into an object in PHP for the purposes of sending it to AWS. The settings below make it through the AWS SDK and up to the server, which I suppose is a good start. But I can't figure out what is wrong.

````
    "OutputGroups" => [
        [
            "CustomName" => "Thumbnails",
            "Name" => "File Group",
            "Outputs" => [
                "ContainerSettings" => [
                    "Container" => "RAW"
                ],
                "VideoDescription" => [
                    "Width" => 1280,
                    "ScalingBehavior" => "DEFAULT",
                    "Height" => 720,
                    "TimecodeInsertion" => "DISABLED",
                    "AntiAlias" => "ENABLED",
                    "Sharpness" => 50,
                    "CodecSettings" => [
                        "Codec" => "FRAME_CAPTURE",
                        "FrameCaptureSettings" => [
                            "FramerateNumerator" => 30,
                            "FramerateDenominator" => 540,
                            "MaxCaptures" => 18,
                            "Quality" => 70
                        ]
                    ],
                    "DropFrameTimecode" => "ENABLED",
                    "ColorMetadata" => "INSERT"
                ],
                ["Extension" => "jpg"],
                ["NameModifier" => "-thumb"]
            ],
            "OutputGroupSettings" => [
                "Type" => "FILE_GROUP_SETTINGS",
                "FileGroupSettings" => [
                    "Destination" => "s3://me/my-folder/"
                ]
            ]
        ],
        [
            "CustomName" => "720p",
            "Name" => "File Group",
            "Outputs" => [
                "ContainerSettings" => [
                    "Container" => "MP4",
                    "Mp4Settings" => [
                        "CslgAtom" => "INCLUDE",
                        "CttsVersion" => 0,
                        "FreeSpaceBox" => "EXCLUDE",
                        "MoovPlacement" => "PROGRESSIVE_DOWNLOAD"
                    ]
                ],
                "VideoDescription" => [
                    "Width" => 1280,
                    "ScalingBehavior" => "DEFAULT",
                    "Height" => 720,
                    "VideoPreprocessors" => [
                        "ImageInserter" => [
                            "InsertableImages" => [
                                "Width" => 200,
                                "Height" => 36,
                                "imageX" => 50,
                                "imageY" => 634,
                                "FadeIn" => 2000,
                                "Layer" => 2,
                                "ImageInserterInput" => "s3://me-again/My-Watermark.tga",
                                "StartTime" => "00:00:05;01",
                                "Opacity" => 50
                            ]
                        ]
                    ],
                    "TimecodeInsertion" => "DISABLED",
                    "AntiAlias" => "ENABLED",
                    "Sharpness" => 50,
                    "CodecSettings" => [
                        "Codec" => "H_264",
                        "H264Settings" => [
                            "InterlaceMode" => "PROGRESSIVE",
                            "NumberReferenceFrames" => 3,
                            "Syntax" => "DEFAULT",
                            "Softness" => 0,
                            "GopClosedCadence" => 1,
                            "GopSize" => 90,
                            "Slices" => 1,
                            "GopBReference" => "DISABLED",
                            "SlowPal" => "DISABLED",
                            "SpatialAdaptiveQuantization" => "ENABLED",
                            "TemporalAdaptiveQuantization" => "ENABLED",
                            "FlickerAdaptiveQuantization" => "DISABLED",
                            "EntropyEncoding" => "CABAC",
                            "Bitrate" => 1800000,
                            "FramerateControl" => "INITIALIZE_FROM_SOURCE",
                            "RateControlMode" => "CBR",
                            "CodecProfile" => "MAIN",
                            "Telecine" => "NONE",
                            "MinIInterval" => 0,
                            "AdaptiveQuantization" => "HIGH",
                            "CodecLevel" => "AUTO",
                            "FieldEncoding" => "PAFF",
                            "SceneChangeDetect" => "ENABLED",
                            "QualityTuningLevel" => "SINGLE_PASS",
                            "FramerateConversionAlgorithm" => "DUPLICATE_DROP",
                            "UnregisteredSeiTimecode" => "DISABLED",
                            "GopSizeUnits" => "FRAMES",
                            "ParControl" => "INITIALIZE_FROM_SOURCE",
                            "NumberBFramesBetweenReferenceFrames" => 2,
                            "RepeatPps" => "DISABLED",
                            "DynamicSubGop" => "STATIC"
                        ]
                    ],
                    "AfdSignaling" => "NONE",
                    "DropFrameTimecode" => "ENABLED",
                    "RespondToAfd" => "NONE",
                    "ColorMetadata" => "INSERT"
                ],
                "AudioDescriptions" => [
                    "AudioTypeControl" => "FOLLOW_INPUT",
                    "AudioSourceName" => "Audio Selector 1",
                    "CodecSettings" => [
                        "Codec" => "AAC",
                        "AacSettings" => [
                            "AudioDescriptionBroadcasterMix" => "NORMAL",
                            "Bitrate" => 96000,
                            "RateControlMode" => "CBR",
                            "CodecProfile" => "LC",
                            "CodingMode" => "CODING_MODE_2_0",
                            "RawFormat" => "NONE",
                            "SampleRate" => 48000,
                            "Specification" => "MPEG4"
                        ]
                    ],
                    "LanguageCodeControl" => "FOLLOW_INPUT"
                ],
                ["Extension" => "mp4"],
                ["NameModifier" => "-720p"]
            ],
            "OutputGroupSettings" => [
                "Type" => "FILE_GROUP_SETTINGS",
                "FileGroupSettings" => [
                    "Destination" => "s3://me/my-folder"
                ]
            ]
        ]
        ],
        "AdAvailOffset" => 0,
    "Inputs" => [
            [
                "AudioSelectors" => [
                    "Audio Selector 1" => [
                        "Offset" => 0,
                        "DefaultSelection" => "DEFAULT",
                        "ProgramSelection" => 1
                    ]
                ],
                "FilterEnable" => "AUTO",
                "PsiControl" => "USE_PSI",
                "FilterStrength" => 0,
                "DeblockFilter" => "DISABLED",
                "DenoiseFilter" => "DISABLED",
                "TimecodeSource" => "EMBEDDED",
                "FileInput" => "s3://me-again/my-folder/my-video.mp4"
            ]
    ],
    "AccelerationSettings" => [
            "Mode" => "DISABLED"
        ],
    "StatusUpdateInterval" => "SECONDS_60",
    "Priority" => 0
    ];```
````

Answer (score 0):

I solved this.

I took the JSON that I got from MediaConvert and then I created my PHP in five steps:

1. Replace all `{` with `array(`
2. Replace all `:` with `=>`
3. Replace all `[` with `array(`
4. Replace all `}` with `)`
5. Replace all `]` with `)`

After doing this it worked perfectly, first time.